# Exclude matching IDs from subquery/cte/temp table in hieracrchy?

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I'm not really sure where to start on this one...

I have one table that contains EMPLOYEE_ID, HOURS_WORKED, DEPARTMENT.
I'm trying to get a random sample of customers in this hierarchical order:

**(1.)** First I want a random sample of 500 of all employees

**(2.)** Next, I want a random sample of 500 employees who work in DEPARTMENT B, and make sure it excludes all EMPLOYEE_ID's of those pulled in (1.)

**(3.)** I want a random sample of 500 employees who work in DEPARTMENT C, and make sure it excludes all EMPLOYEE_ID's of those pulled in (1.) and (2.)

Could someone provide me some details on how to go about doing this? I am new to this and have never ran such a query before, thus the more detail the better!

My hunch is that it will require me to make *temp tables along the way and use a UNION ALL at the end to combine everything*? I am using Postgresql to interact with Amazon Redshift.

Comment: For 1. you could go with: `SELECT * FROM tbl ORDER BY random LIMIT 500; `. The resting two Queries should be straight forward

Comment: Hi Tony, 1. was straight forward. I'm not sure how do execute 2 and 3, where I would be excluding the customers pulled before it.

Answer (score 0):

You can try if using CTEs works for you.

```
WITH
x AS
(
SELECT *
       FROM elbat t
       ORDER BY random()
       LIMIT 500
),
b AS
(
SELECT *
       FROM elbat t
       WHERE t.department = 'B'
             AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                                    FROM x
                                    WHERE t.employee_id = x.employee_id)
       ORDER BY random()
       LIMIT 500
),
c AS
(
SELECT *
       FROM elbat t
       WHERE t.department = 'C'
             AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                                    FROM x
                                    WHERE t.employee_id = x.employee_id)
             AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                                    FROM b
                                    WHERE t.employee_id = b.employee_id)
       ORDER BY random()
       LIMIT 500
)
SELECT *
       FROM x
UNION ALL
SELECT *
       FROM b
UNION ALL
SELECT *
       FROM c;
```